# OnMove() being called immediately instead of waiting for an actual move of the Window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm having trouble with my MFC application
It's supposed to display the coordinates of the window, and then when you move the window, display a new line with the new coordinates. My problem is that the OnMove() function seems to be called immediately and everything is always displayed all at once.

Here is my code for OnPaint():

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{

CRect rect;
HWND hWnd;
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
GetClientRect(&rect);

CString topLeftx, topLefty, topRightx, topRighty;
CString bottomLeftx, bottomLefty, bottomRightx, bottomRighty;
CString topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;
CString topLeftxL, topLeftyL, topRightxL, topRightyL;
CString bottomLeftxL, bottomLeftyL, bottomRightxL, bottomRightyL;
CString topLeftL, topRightL, bottomLeftL, bottomRightL;


topLeftx.Format(_T("%d"), (rect.TopLeft().x));
topLefty.Format(_T("%d"), rect.TopLeft().y);
topLeft = topLeftx + "," + topLefty;

topRightx.Format(_T("%d"), rect.TopLeft().x + rect.Width());
topRighty.Format(_T("%d"), rect.TopLeft().y);
topRight = topRightx + "," + topRighty;

bottomLeftx.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().x - rect.Width());
bottomLefty.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().y);
bottomLeft = bottomLeftx + "," + bottomLefty;

bottomRightx.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().x);
bottomRighty.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().y);
bottomRight = bottomRightx + "," + bottomRighty;

GetWindowRect(&rect);

topLeftxL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.left);
topLeftyL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.top);
topLeftL = topLeftxL + "," + topLeftyL;

topRightxL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.TopLeft().x + rect.Width());
topRightyL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.TopLeft().y);
topRightL = topRightxL + "," + topRightyL;

bottomLeftxL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().x - rect.Width());
bottomLeftyL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().y);
bottomLeftL = bottomLeftxL + "," + bottomLeftyL;

bottomRightxL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().x);
bottomRightyL.Format(_T("%d"), rect.BottomRight().y);
bottomRightL = bottomRightxL + "," + bottomRightyL;




dc.TextOutW(0, 20, _T("Hello from ROSSSSSSS!!!!"));
dc.TextOutW(0, 40, _T("TopLeft:"));
dc.TextOutW(60, 40, topLeft);
dc.TextOutW(130, 40, _T("TopRight:"));
dc.TextOutW(200, 40, topRight);
dc.TextOutW(280, 40, _T("BottomLeft:"));
dc.TextOutW(365, 40, bottomLeft);
dc.TextOutW(445, 40, _T("BottomRight:"));
dc.TextOutW(550, 40, bottomRight);
dc.TextOutW(0, 60, _T("TopLeft:"));
dc.TextOutW(60, 60, topLeftL);
dc.TextOutW(130, 60, _T("TopRight:"));
dc.TextOutW(200, 60, topRightL);
dc.TextOutW(280, 60, _T("BottomLeft:"));
dc.TextOutW(365, 60, bottomLeftL);
dc.TextOutW(445, 60, _T("BottomRight:"));
dc.TextOutW(550, 60, bottomRightL);



Invalidate();
UpdateWindow();
}
```

And here is OnMove

```
void CMainFrame::OnMove(int x, int y)

{
CFrameWnd::OnMove(x, y);
CDC *dc;

dc = GetDC();
Invalidate();

dc->TextOutW(0, 80, _T("TEST"));

UpdateWindow();

}
```

Any idea why the word TEST appears as soon as I run the application instead of waiting for a move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the initial creation and display of a window causes a call to OnMove(). Another hint - you will save many headaches by only drawing text in the OnPaint() function. Other message handlers should capture data for later use by OnPaint(), and not do the drawing immediately.